# How to print char value from struct hold in header file?

Tags: c, struct

I've recently started learning C language and I've come to my first problem. I am currently trying to print value from `struct typedef node` located in in the header file `menu.h` which looks like this :

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct node
{
    long nodeID;
    char *name;
    struct node *child;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct menu
{
    node  **array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} menu;

void initMenu(menu*,size_t);

void addNode(menu*,node*);

node* searchMenu(menu*,long*);

void freeMenu(menu*);



node* new_node(long,char*);

node* add_child(node*, node*);


node* search_node(node*,long*);
```

Structure menu is just an array of nodes. 
The problem is that then I try to print names from nodes which are hold in a menu structure it returns me something like this:

```
   �b�x��b�x�
```

Why is that? I have tried playing around with pointers as initially I thought it is a problem connected with them, but I have achieved nothing apart from compilation errors. Values and are assigned in a `main.c` in a functions processA and processB :

```
void processA(char *str,menu *c)
    {
        char leftPart[4];
        char rightPart[100];
        strncpy(leftPart,str,4);
        memmove(&rightPart,str+4,strlen(str));

        long nodeId = strtol(leftPart,NULL,10);
        addNode(c,new_node(nodeId,rightPart));


    }

    void processB(char *str,menu *c)
    {
        char leftPart[4];
        strncpy(leftPart,str,4);
        memmove(str,str+4,strlen(str));
        long childNodeId = strtol(leftPart,NULL,10);
        long parentNodeId = strtol(str,NULL,10);
        if(parentNodeId > 0) {
            add_child(searchMenu(c, &parentNodeId), searchMenu(c, &childNodeId));
            printf("%s\n %s\n ",searchMenu(c, &parentNodeId)->name, searchMenu(c, &childNodeId)->name); //prints the name of the node

        }
    }
```

P.S I am really sorry if the solution is straight forward , I just started learning C :)

**EDIT:**

Here is the menu.c and the main method:
menu.c :

```
void initMenu(menu *m, size_t init) {
    m->array= malloc(sizeof(node)*init);
    for(int i= 0;i<init;i++){
        m->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }
    m->used= 0;
    m->size = init;
}

void addNode(menu *m, node *n) {
    if (m->used == m->size) {
        m->size *= 2;
        m->array = (node **) realloc(m->array, m->size * sizeof(node));
    }
    m->array[m->used++] = n;
}

node *searchMenu(menu *m, long *n) {
    for(int i = 0;i < m->used;i++)
    {
        if(m->array[i]->nodeID == *n)
        {

            return m->array[i];
        }
    }

}



void freeMenu(menu *m)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<m->used;i++){

        m->array[i]->nodeID = NULL;
        m->array[i]->child = NULL;
        m->array[i]->next = NULL;
    }
    free(m->array);
    m->array = NULL;
    m->used = 0;
    m->size = 0;
}

node* new_node(long nodeID,char* name)
{
    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new) {
        new->name = name;
        new->nodeID = nodeID;
        new->child = NULL;
        new->next = NULL;
    }

    return new;
}

node* add_next(node* a,node* b)
{
    if (a==NULL)
        return NULL;
    while (a->next)
        a = a->next;
    return (a->next = b);
}

node* add_child(node* a,node* b)
{
    if (a==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (a->child)
        return add_next(a->child, b);
    else
        return (a->child = b);
}

node* search_node(node* root, long *id)
{
    if(root == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"No tree inserted! Please insert the tree");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(root->nodeID == *id){
        return root;
    }
    node *found;
    if((found = search_node(root->next,id)) != NULL){
        return found;
    }
    return search_node(root->child,id);
}
```

Comment: Most of the relevant code is missing. Please provide a [MCVE] and read this: [ask].

Comment: Where is `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `memmove` but that's probably contributing to your issues. Just copy a string using string-copy routines strncpy etc.

But the cause will be that your assigning the structure's `name` member to the local variable `rightPart`. Once that function call is complete `rightPart` is no longer valid. Don't use char pointers but instead make char *name into char name[100] in your struct.

Once that's working you can uplevel the code by using dynamic memory allocation for the name string etc.

Comment: Thanks for giving a clue! Works perfectly!